# "up to associates" phrase meaning in proof of irreducible zeroes

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain

This is what is trying to be proved:

> Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over a field $F$.  If $F$ has
>   characteristic $0$, then $f(x)$ has no multiple $0$'s.

The proof starts off with:  If $f(x)$ has a multiple zero, then, by a previous theorem, $f(x)$ and $f '(x)$ have a common divisor of positive degree in $F[x]$.  Since the only divisor of positive degree of $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ is $f(x)$ itself (up to associates), we see that $f(x)$ divides $f'(x)$.

What does the phrase "up to associates" mean here?  I know that two elements $(a,b)$ of an integral domain are associates iff $a = ub$, where $u$ is a unit of the integral domain.  But I don't understand what up to associates means in this context.

Comment: associates differ by a multiplicative unit.  Thus, over $\mathbb Q$ say, $x$ and $-x$ are associates (as are $x, 2x$ or indeed $x,\lambda x$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb Q^*$).

Comment: I don't understand.  What does "up to associates" mean when I'm talking about $f(x)$ being its own divisor?

Comment: $x$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$, yes?  Yet I can write $x=(-1)\times (-x)$.  That "factoring" doesn't count because $-x$ is an associate of $x$.

Comment: One would like to say that," if $f(x)$ is irreducible, then $f(x)$ is the only polynomial that divides $f(x)$."  That statement is, however, false because of associates.  Thus $-x$ does in fact divide $x$.  Other than that kind of example, though, the statement is true.

Comment: I still don't understand.  What specifically does the phrase "up to associates" mean here?  Because based on what you said, any of the associates should divide $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ and therefore there isn't only one divisor?

Comment: Just means "the only divisors of $f(x)$ of positive degree are the associates of $f(x)$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context it means that the only divisors of $f$ are (non-zero) constants and polynomials of the form $\lambda f$, with $\lambda\in\Bbb F^\times$.

In general, *up to* X means "if we pretend that two things differing only by X are the same", and X is generally some kind of equivalence relation. Examples :

> There is only one group with two elements, up to isomorphism.

Here "up to isomorphism" means that we don't make a distinction between two isomorphic groups, so that $(\{1,-1\},\cdot )$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

> Every natural number greater that $1$ can be factorised as a product of prime numbers, and this factorisation is unique up to the order of the factors.

Here "up to the order of the factors" means that we don't make a distinction between two factorisations which have the same primes but in a different order, so for example $6=2\times 3$ and $6=3\times 2$ are considered to be the same factorisation.

Comment: So would it be fair to say "up to" is equivalent to "within the same equivalence class" depending on what you're looking at?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.