# Meaning of "up to associates" in unique prime factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, gaussian-integers

We know that the Euclidean Domain has the property of Unique Factorization.

More precisely, *every nonzero element in a Euclidean ring $R$ can be uniquely written (up to associates) as a product of prime elements or is a unit in $R$.*

The word "up to associates" confusing me a bit.

**P.S.** Let's consider the example in the euclidean domain $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and consider the following prime factorizations such as: $$(2+i)(1+i) \quad\text{and} \quad (-1+2i)(1-i)$$
Note that $2+i\sim -1+2i$ and $1+i\sim 1-i$.

Can anyone explain me the meaning of the phrase "up to associates" in the above example, please?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933073/up-to-associates-phrase-meaning-in-proof-of-irreducible-zeroes

Comment: If $ab$ is one prime factorization, then for any unit $u$, we can get another prime factorization $(au)(u^{-1}b)$, So the factorization is only unique except for ("up to") the replacement of $a$ by the associate $au$ and $b$ by the corresponding associate $u^{-1}b$, where $u$ is any unit. In your example, $a=2+i$, $b = 1+i$, and $u=i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Uniqueness of factorization up to associates* means that if $r\in R$, nonzero and not a unit, is written as
$$
r = p_1p_2\dots p_m = q_1q_2\dots q_n
$$
with $p_i$ and $q_j$ irreducible, then

1. $m=n$
2. there exists a permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ such that, for $i=1,2,\dots,m$, $p_i$ is associate to $q_{\sigma(i)}$.

Two elements $a$ and $b$ are associate if there is a unit $u$ with $b=ua$.

This happens also in the integers: for instance, $6=2\cdot3=(-3)(-2)$.

In your case, $2+i$ is associate to $-1+2i$ and $1+i$ is associate to $1-i$.

Comment: Let's consider another example: $(2+i)(1+i)$ and $(-1+2i)(1+i)$.  Are these prime factorizations equal? Since $2+i\sim -1+2i$ and 1+i\sim 1+i$.

Comment: @RFZ The products are different. They're factorizations of associate elements.

Comment: Hmm Thanks! I was thinking that uniqueness of factorization up to associates is something like that: for example, we have two primes $\pi_1, \pi_2$ then $\pi_1\pi_2$ is the same as $u\pi_1\pi_2$ where $u$ - some unit of $R$.

Comment: In other words, if we have one factorization into primes and we multiply it by some unit $u$ then these two factorizations are the same!

Comment: @RFZ Not really; say $r=pq$, with $p$ and $q$ irreducible; if $u$ is a unit, then $r=(pu)(qu^{-1})$ is another factorization, but the factors are associate to the ones in the other factorization.

Answer (score 3):

This means the prime factors are determined only up to a unit factor. Indeed in the Gaussian integers, the group of units is $\;\{1,-1,i,-i\}$ and indeed
$$2+i=(-i)(-1+2i),\qquad 1+i=i(1-i).$$
We have the same situation in $\mathbf Z$, where $\mathbf Z^\times=\{1,-1\}$, and, for instance
$$6=2\cdot 3=(-2)\cdot(-3)$$

Answer (score 0):

In the ordinary integers the factorizations
$$
6 = 2\times 3 = (-2) \times (-3)
$$
are equivalent *up to associates* because $2$ and $-2$ are associates because
$$
-2 = (-1) \times 2
$$
and $(-1)$ is a *unit* - it has a multiplicative inverse.

In the Gaussian integers $2+i$ and $-1 + 2i$ are associates because
$$
-1 + 2i = i \times (2 +i)
$$
and $(-i)$ is a unit because it has a multiplicative inverse, namely $i$.

In the integers you don't usually have to fuss with "up to associates" since there is a natural way to specify that primes should be positive. In the Gaussian integers there is no good way to distinguish among the associates
$$
2+i, -2 -i, -1 + 2i, 1 - 2i \ .
$$